# Different Word 2016 equation editors

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2016, equation-editor

With the new Microsoft Word 2016 if you insert an equation through the Equation button within the Insert menu you get this new-looking editor.

[image]

Equations created in such a way can be viewed in inline, professional or linear mode and offer advanced options.

But if you use a keyboard shortcut (Alt+= or any user defined one) instead you end up getting this old-fashioned editor:
[image]
[image]

And if you edit equations from documents made by other people sometimes they are opened with the new editor, sometimes with the old one.

Can anyone explain the difference between them and how to force Word to always use the new one, please?
I would like to get it with a keyboard shortcut.
And also how to convert an equation made with the old editor onto the new format?

Regards

Comment: Could you please try Alt+* instead of Alt+= ? It worked for me.

Comment: Hello @ErdoganCEVHER in my word (Spanish) Alt+* doesn't do anything, at lest the main keyboard, I don't num keyboard.

Comment: The command for NEW version of MS Equation Editor is "Add New Equation" in MS Word 2016. Unfortunately, I cannot find it in "File - Options - Customize Ribbon - Keyboard Shortcuts - Categories: AllCommands - Commands panel" on the right. That said, The shortcut via "File - Options - Customize Ribbon - Keyboard Shortcuts - Categories: Add Tab - Commands panel:AddEquation" adds OLD version of MS Equation Editor.

Comment: I was going to say I can't find that command. https://i.imgur.com/uLXlKeJ.png  Do you know how to transform from an old format equation to a new one or viceversa? Or is it suggested to use one of them instead of the other one?